# Why is there a warning "Return value is expected to be XXX, YYY returned "?

Tags: php, oop

```php
class AbstractModel {}
class UserModel extends AbstractModel {}

abstract class AbstractMapper
{
    public function getById(int $id): AbstractModel {}
}

class UserMapper extends AbstractMapper
{
    public function foo(): UserModel
    {
        // PhpStorm: Return value is expected 
        // to be 'UserModel', 'AbstractModel' returned 
        return $this->getById(111); 
    }
}
```

I don't understand why there is a warning from PhpStorm. Is there a mistake here?
It seems to me that there should be no mistake. The `UserModel` object is a subtype of the `AbstractModel` object. But this code works... but PhpStorm highlights the string as erroneous. Where is the truth?

Comment: "But this code works" - have you tried actually returning something from the getById() function as defined in the abstract class? https://3v4l.org/v2gaQ

Comment: If you do eventually overload the function in the child class it will work again: https://3v4l.org/B6rIU

Comment: Yes, I have tried and it works: https://3v4l.org/BKqF5

Comment: So your base class will perform factory-like things and is aware of child classes then? PhpStorm can't interpret all of your intensions, so although your logic happens to work for this case, it isn't guaranteed to work in all cases, and that's why you are getting the warning.

Comment: > your base class will perform factory-like 

Yes. Ok.

Comment: The above code, as typed **won't generate the warning that you say in PhpStorm**. Please code the correct code that demonstrate the specific behavior. (It will show a different error, though). https://cln.sh/ff5bfjJnpKkyM7vYGLVW

Comment: @yivi, my PhpStorm is giving the error as reported by the OP, although I don't know if it is PhpStorm itself or some extension. https://imgur.com/a/emsf82j

Comment: ok, Thanks @ChrisHaas Might be IDE version, or more likely what type of code analysis is enabled for the project.

Answer (score 1):

You define `getById()` to return an instance of `AbstractModel`, if you then return the output of `getById()` in `foo()` where you define that `foo()` should return an instance of `UserModel` you have a conflict between both return type definitions.

Comment: The problem is in the PhpStorm editor, but the PHP code executes: https://3v4l.org/BKqF5

Comment: Yeah because PHP handles this at run time and does the type checking then.  But PHPStorm is pointing out that `getById` can return any `AbstractModel` some of which may not be a `UserModel` and warning you that their could be a problem.  PHP won't error until a non-`UserModel` class is attempted to return.